# PHP DOM textContent vs nodeValue?

Tags: php, html, dom

PHP DOMnode objects contain a [textContent](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) and [nodeValue](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) attributes which both seem to be the innerHTML of the node.

> nodeValue: The value of this node, depending on its type
>
> textContent: This attribute returns the text content of this node and its descendants.

What is the difference between these two properties? When is it proper to use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I finally wanted to know the difference as well, so I dug into the [source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/dom/php_dom.c) and found the answer; in most cases there will be no discernible difference, but there are a bunch of edge cases you should be aware of.

Both `->nodeValue` and `->textContent` are identical for the following classes (node types):

- [`DOMAttr`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domattr.php)
- [`DOMText`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php)
- [`DOMElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)
- [`DOMComment`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domcomment.php)
- [`DOMCharacterData`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domcharacterdata.php)
- [`DOMProcessingInstruction`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domprocessinginstruction.php)

The `->nodeValue` property yields `NULL` for the following classes (node types):

- [`DOMDocumentFragment`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumentfragment.php)
- [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- [`DOMNotation`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnotation.php)
- [`DOMEntity`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domentity.php)
- [`DOMEntityReference`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domentityreference.php)

The `->textContent` property is non-existent for the following classes:

- `DOMNameSpaceNode` (not documented, but can be found with `//namespace:*` selector)

The `->nodeValue` property is non-existent for the following classes:

- [`DOMDocumentType`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocumenttype.php)

See also: [`dom_node_node_value_read()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/dom/node.c#288) and [`dom_node_text_content_read()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/dom/node.c#917)

Answer (score 20):

Hope this will make sense:

```
$doc = DOMDocument::loadXML('<body><!-- test --><node attr="test1">old content<h1>test</h1></node></body>');
var_dump($doc->textContent);
var_dump($doc->nodeValue);
var_dump($doc->firstChild->textContent);
var_dump($doc->firstChild->nodeValue);
```

Output:

```
string(15) "old contenttest"
NULL
string(15) "old contenttest"
string(15) "old contenttest"
```

Because:
    [nodeValue - The value of this node, depending on its type](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue)

Comment: The nodeValue for a DOMDocument is NULL then ?

Answer (score 10):

Both `textContent` and `nodeValue` return unescaped text; i.e. `&lt;` becomes `<`.

`textContent` concatenates together all of the content of all children. This is an important distinction; for example, in Chrome the maximum length of `nodeValue` is 65536 characters (not bytes); if you have already set the content of a node to something longer than that you will need to iterate child nodes if you want to use `nodeValue` whereas `textContent` will perform the concatenation for you.

As discussed, there are also several DOM classes that do not support `nodeValue` but do support `textContent`.

`nodeValue` is faster for obvious reasons; however don't use it unless you know exactly what the node structure really is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assigning a value to the `textContent` property note that it doesn't work for [PHP < 5.6.1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent). Consider using `nodeValue` instead, for backward compatibility.

Answer (score -4):

They're the same thing. (mikespook's NULL is from a non-DOMNode)

Comment: Nope, DOMDocument is a descendent of DOMNode; the implementation of the property getter just defines the value as NULL.

Comment: Huh? The question is about DOMNode, not DOMDocument.

Comment: Yes, well, DOMDocument is also a DOMNode isn't it? I was referring specifically to the comment made about mike's answer.