# remove javascript syntax from string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to index the content of my site and since there is some javascript inside the `<body></body>`, it stores that as well of the content.

It actually gets everything in-between the `<body></body>`, but I use PHP's strip_tags to remove the HTML tags.

It removes the `<script>` tags, as they are HTML tags, but the javascript syntax remains.

How can I remove the javascript syntax?

Here is example of the content with the javascript syntax in it:

> "Watch Later Added to Private videos will be skipped if viewers don't
>   have access, but playlist notes are publicly visible. Back to list
>   Added to playlist: Private videos will be skipped if viewers don't
>   have access, but playlist notes are publicly visible. Add an optional
>   note150 Add note Saving note... Note added to: Error adding note:
>   Click to add a new note if (window.ytcsi) {ytcsi.tick("js_head");}
>   yt.pubsub.subscribe('init',
>   yt.www.brandedpage.channels4init.overviewTabInit);
>   yt.pubsub.subscribe('dispose',
>   yt.www.brandedpage.channels4init.overviewTabDispose);
>   yt.setAjaxToken('c4_shelves_ajax',
>   "0qjmgZRNi5AAlV5LrkVIKyY1_VZ8MTM2ODkyNTgzM0AxMzY4ODM5NDMz");"

How can I get it so that it is just

> "Watch Later Added to Private videos will be skipped if viewers don't
>   have access, but playlist notes are publicly visible. Back to list
>   Added to playlist: Private videos will be skipped if viewers don't
>   have access, but playlist notes are publicly visible. Add an optional
>   note150 Add note Saving note... Note added to: Error adding note:
>   Click to add a new note"

Comment: Use a HTML parser for that. It also has textContent.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380919/php-dom-textcontent-vs-nodevalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can first remove the `script` tags from your text with their content , and then run `strip_tags` on the result

removing the script tag can be made in many ways, one of those is regular expression:

```
$pattern = '/\<script.*\<\/script\>/iU'; //notice the U flag - it is important here
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '', $text);
$text = strip_tags($text);
```

another way (without using REGEX but less elegant):

```
while(($pos = stripos($text,"<script"))!==false){
    $end_pos = stripos($text,"</script>");
    $start = substr($text, 0, $pos);
    $end = substr($text, $end_pos+strlen("</script>"));
    $text = $start.$end;
}
$text = strip_tags($text);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without regex? It is just that I am not using regex at all and would prefer not to.

Comment: yes, but it is way less elegant. you can achieve the same result by finding all the occurrences of `<script` and all the occurrences of `</script>` and then take `substr` before and after and concatenate them for example

Comment: That seems very ugly. Okay, thank you.

Comment: one more question. Why can't one just do `$text = preg_replace('/\<script.*\<\/script\>/iU', '', $text);` ?

Comment: I've never said it can't be done - I just separated the pattern for more clarity on the code, you may do it if you wish.
you can also do `$text = strip_tags(preg_replace('/\<script.*\<\/script\>/iU', '', $text));` and save the second line as well

Comment: Ah, okay. Also, I am trying the regex in http://http://www.debuggex.com/ and it doesn't seem to be working. I have `/\<script.*\<\/script\>/iU` as the regex and `Hello how are you <script> var i; </script> I am doing good. This is <script type="text/javascript"> var k; if for </script> random content` as the string.

Comment: @IMUXIxD I've tried it both in http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/ and in my code, and the result was `Hello how are you I am doing good. This is random content`, check again if you have any mistakes
(the site you provided doesn't seem to be valid - make sure it runs the test on PHP PCRE regex engine - other engine may perform differently)

Comment: @Yaron the problem with your regexp is input like this: `text1<script>var a = "</script>";</script>text2`. It will give `text1";</script>text2` instead of `text1text2`. This probably is what OP's input looks like. You _can not_ do this with a regexp.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I ended up using the non regex solution, even though it is ugly, it works for me.