# PHP nodeElement delivered by Angular has no value

Tags: php, angularjs, xpath

So I'm retrieving a page through curl and I have a xpath query that selects a

from the page. The selected node element though has no nodeValue, but at the same time I can get other attributes like the "data-title" and "data-role" attributes. 
Here's my code:

```
$username = $xpath->query('//div[@id="username"]//p[1]');
echo $username -> length; //returns 1
echo $username -> item(0) -> getAttribute("data-role"); //works
echo $username -> item(0) -> nodeValue; //empty
```

and the HTML code I'm receiving looks like that:

```
<div id = "username">
    <p data-role="date" data-title="Bonjour {name}...">
    Bonjour Username, 
         <span class="msg-expire-3">Your subscription will expire on 21/10/2015</span>
         <a href="/..." class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Renew it</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont see `div[@id="username` in your HTML code. Also `nodeValue` is defined only for text elements (nodes).

Comment: @Ahmed you misinterpreted the xpath selector which is looking for a `<p>`

Comment: Have you confirmed that the element isn't being populated with ajax? Check the page source in browser

Comment: Try to add text `Bonjour Username,` to `<span>` element

Comment: I just didn't include the parent in the post, sorry. @charlietfl - it is actually delivered by an Ajax request, any ideas how can I get to that since I'm loading the page in php through curl

Comment: Would need to use a headless browser to allow ajax to do it's thing, and after delay retrieve html

Comment: The `nodeValue` is not empty, I can't reproduce that: https://3v4l.org/JtrIZ - Please check if there is an issue with your question's code. See as well [PHP DOM textContent vs nodeValue?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12380919/367456)