# Get tags values from every tag inside nested tags in html with php

Tags: php, html

I'm working in code that get all tags values "Text only" from html file. But if any tag has nested tags it will go inside Childs and get the the tag value that hasn't a child.
I tried this one but it has a bit of missing

php code:

```
$dochtml = new DOMDocument();
$dochtml->loadHTMLFile("index2.html");
$nodes = $dochtml ->getElementsByTagName("a"); 
gettagsvalue($nodes);
  function gettagsvalue($nodes){
    if($nodes->length != 0){
      for ($i=0;$i<$nodes->length;$i++){
        foreach ($tags=["h1","h2","h3","h4","h5","h6","h7","a","img","li","span","p","pre","i","strong","div","ul"] as $tag){  
          if($nodes->item($i)->getElementsByTagName($tag)->length != 0){
            if ($nodes->item($i)->getElementsByTagName($tag)->length == 1){
              echo "here"."<br><br><br> $tag";
              echo "<pre>" ;print_r($nodes->item($i)->getElementsByTagName($tag)->item(0));echo "</pre>" ;             
            }else{
              echo "there"."<br><br><br> $tag";
              gettagsvalue($nodes->item($i)->getElementsByTagName($tag));
              // echo "$tag <br><br><br>";
            }
            // print_r($nodes->item($i)->getElementsByTagName($tag));echo "<br>"; 
          }        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i expected to get

"Green"
"valley"

HTML:

```
<a href="index.html" id="aaaaaaaaaaaa2015284957">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="50px" height="50px" id="imgaaaaaaaaaaimg732756221">
    <span>Green</span>
    <span id="spanaaaaaaaaaaspan1106733773">Valley</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using textContent property? This should concatenate text nodes of all nested nodes.
See [php domdocument read element inner text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054815/php-domdocument-read-element-inner-text) and [PHP DOM textContent vs nodeValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380919/php-dom-textcontent-vs-nodevalue) for more details.

Comment: Actually i don't need that i need every single value to store it after that in DB
But if get element has child it get inner HTML not text only